# Analyze the role of "had the Chinese not come" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, comprehension

What is the role of **had the Chinese not come** in this sentence?  What is the relationship of the second half of this sentence to the first?

> The significance of decorations on Chinese pottery may have remained clear **had the Chinese not come** under foreign influence.

Comment: Related question, [The use of "were- should- had” at the beginning of sentences instead of “if”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233992/the-use-of-were-should-had-at-the-beginning-of-sentences-instead-of-if) and [What does “would not have been possible had I remained” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177784/what-does-would-not-have-been-possible-had-i-remained-mean/178010#178010) and [Had you had asked](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156077/had-you-had-asked)

Comment: [What does that mean “had you not seen”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280473/what-does-that-mean-had-you-not-seen/280527#280527) and [What's the correct usage of this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103749/whats-the-correct-usage-of-this-sentence) and [The third conditional questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252124/the-third-conditional-questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambridge Online Dictionaries offers the following explanation:

> Had you (Had with inversion)
>
> **In formal situations, we can use had + subject + verb instead of if in third** **conditional sentences**:
>
> Had I known you were waiting outside, I would have invited you to come in. (If I had known you were waiting outside …)
>
> Had Margaret realised she would be travelling alone, she would never

So, in your sentence above, just replace the "had the Chinese not come" with "if the Chinese hadn't come."